# Programming sensor to follow light

Tags: nxt

[image]
Cannot get sensor to follow light on other moving robot.

Comment: This is a duplicate of your previous question.  You shouldn't open multiple questions to solve the same problems.  Update your existing question and respond to some of the questions in the comments and you will get a better answer.

Comment: I've moved your image into your original question for you.